# Bootstrap 5: Nav bar Toggler not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

The javascript toggle element of my toggle collapse and expand doesn't work. This is my first project in javascript and i feel i must be doing something basic wrong.

I have the Nav bar set up so that the toggle is active at all screen sizes and the logo is central as this is a one page Game.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SPLANETS</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="assets/img/splanetsfavicon.png" rel="icon">
    <!-- Main Bootstrap Css-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Main CSS File -->
    <link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Icons-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/128d236a07.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body id="bg-space">
    <!-- === Header === -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span ><i class="earth-icon fa-solid fa-earth-americas"></i></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/templogo.png" alt="Splanets Logo" class="img-fluid "></a>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- End of Header -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included both bootstrap js file links at the bottom of the file and tested and everything loads correctly.

I have taken away my code and copied over the bootstrap nav and still i get no interactivity from the toggle.

Comment: This code as is works on Chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome and it still isn't working

Comment: Anis somehow it is now working - head in hands moment thank you for checking it for me!